# Disable DHCPv6 client in Windows

Tags: windows, ipv6, netsh, dhcpv6

I don't quite understand the link between 4 parameters related to IPv6 stateful and stateless autoconfiguration used under `netsh int ipv6 set interface` command context in Windows:

- `advertise`
- `routerdescovery`
- `managedaddress`
- `otherstateful`

From what I could find around so far, I understand that:

- `advertise` is used to indicate that RA should be emited/responded by OS containing the `M` and `O` flag configured as `managedaddress` and `otherstateful` for that particular interface; this is relevant to a server.
- `routerdescovery` is used to indicate that OS should request/process RA on that interface and use it to configure itself based on what flags the RA has; if `routerdescovery` is enabled, `managedaddress` and `otherstateful` are overridden by RA's flags; this is relevant to a client

My question is what happens when `advertise` and `routerdescovery` are disabled?

You would think that in this case, `managedaddress` and `otherstateful` determines whether or not DHCPv6 client is enabled or not on that interface. However, it doesn't seem to be so. If all 4 parameters are disabled (`advertise`, `routerdescovery`, `managedaddress` and `otherstateful`) Windows client will still try to contact a DHCPv6 server.

Comment: Great question. I don't know what they all mean either. All I know is that if I disable only `routerdiscovery` that's enough to keep my machines from acquiring an IPv6 address from the router.

Comment: @RyanRies Only if Router Advertisement has the `M` flag not set (stateless autoconfiguration).

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

After many experiments and a lot of ambiguous docs and articles, I have deducted that `managedaddress` and `otherstateful` are relevant only in conjunction with `advertise`(i.e. when you enable RA on your Windows server) and they help setting the `M` and `O` flags in the RA packets.

If `routerdescovery` is enabled and `advertise` disabled, you can't configure `managedaddress` and `otherstateful` parameters through netsh anymore, but as soon as an RA arrives on the interface, these two parameters are configured automatically so that they reflect the `M` and `O` flags of the arrived RA packet.

Regardless which configuration is used, DHCPv6 Solicit messages are always sent on IPv6 enabled interfaces, even when receiving RA packets with `M` flag NOT set. I could not find a way to disable DHCPv6 on Windows (I assume Vista and above; I tested on 8.1). If there is a DHCPv6 server on the network you will get an IPv6 address from it.

Luckily, most networks use stateless autoconfiguration (each node configure itself based on the prefix advertised in the RA) instead of stateful autoconfiguration where an IPv6 address is negotiated with a DHCPv6 server. Because most networks are stateless, many people thought that disabling `routerdiscovery` will stop them from getting additional IPv6 addresses. But this is not valid if there is a DHCPv6 server on the network.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to add in case this was useful. The command I use for disabling DHCPv6 and router discovery for IPv6 on all of a system's network interfaces is as follows:

```
Set-NetIPInterface `
  -AddressFamily IPv6 `
  -InterfaceIndex $(Get-NetIpInterface -AddressFamily IPv6 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex) `
  -RouterDiscovery disabled `
  -Dhcp Disabled
```

In addition to that, I also set a system to prefer IPv4 over IPv6. Reboot is required for this change to take effect.

```
New-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters" -Name "DisabledComponents" -Value 0x20 -PropertyType "DWORD"
#If DisabledComponents exists, use the set cmdlet
Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters\" -Name "DisabledComponents" -Value 0x20
#You need to reboot the computer in order for the changes to take effect
Restart-Computer
```